# How to define data type in GHCi

Tags: haskell

I'm reading from "[Making Our Own Types and Typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)" part from "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!".

By following the text I wrote the code in GHCi and got an error.

```
data Shape = Circle Float Float Float | Rectangle Float Float Float Float   
surface :: Shape -> Float

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: surface :: Shape -> Float
```

When I write the code by text editor and load from GHCi, it works without problem.

How should I define data type in GHCi?

Comment: There are alternatives, but IMO using an editor is the best way, since it allows one to change the previously defined entities (typo fixes, new experiments, ...) without re-typing all the code. Every time I start typing in GHCi non trivial code I find myself to regret I did not use an editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined the data type correctly, but when you want to enter a multi-line statement in GHCi, you need to use `:{` and `:}`, or use another mechanism to make multi-line statements. You thus can enter this with:

```
Prelude> data Shape = Circle Float Float Float | Rectangle Float Float Float Float
Prelude> :{
Prelude| surface :: Shape -> Float
Prelude| surface (Circle _ _ r) = pi * r ^ 2
Prelude| surface (Rectangle x1 y1 x2 y2) = (abs $ x2 - x1) * (abs $ y2 - y1)
Prelude| :}
```